# How to kill background task from another session?

Tags: linux, bash, background-process

I've run a multithreading program in background:

```
./my_task &
```

Then I logged out, then logged again. Now `jobs` command does not show this program, but `top` does show the threads of this program. So it is still running. How to stop it? I guess I can kill each thread, but there are many of them and I don't know how it will affect `my_task` program.

I am using Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In common case, you can use

```
ps aux | grep my_task
```

-or, if you know, that process name starts with "my_task" exactly:

```
ps aux | grep [m]y_task
```

(this will exclude `grep` process itself from result table)

to get desired process id (let it be `$pid`) and then kill it with `kill $pid`

*edit* (thanks to comments below): `jobs` is part of `bash` itself, and so information about it is listed in `man bash` page:

> Job  control  refers to the ability to selectively stop (suspend) the
>   execution of processes and continue
>          (resume) their execution at a later point.  A user typically employs this  facility  via  an  interactive
>          interface supplied jointly by the operating system kernel's terminal driver and bash.
>
> ```
>    The  shell  associates a job with each pipeline.  It keeps a table of currently executing jobs, which may
>    be listed with the jobs command.  When bash starts a job asynchronously (in the background), it prints  a
>    line that looks like:
>
>           [1] 25647
>
>    indicating  that  this  job  is  job number 1 and that the process ID of the last process in the pipeline
>    associated with this job is 25647.  All of the processes in a single pipeline are  members  of  the  same
>    job.  Bash uses the job abstraction as the basis for job control.
> ```

but this will not help a case since it will list jobs only for current instance (which, of cause, will change when you're changing your session)

Comment: It's in Debian Squeeze. I don't know what is my jobs command. How to tell this?

Comment: @cpp you can check it with `which jobs`

Comment: There is no output after `which jobs`

Comment: @cpp then try `alias | grep jobs`

Comment: No output after `alias | grep jobs`.

Comment: Then there's no standard `jobs` command nor alias for it. I don't know what do you mean with this `jobs` command then

Comment: jobs - list the active jobs. It is a bash command

Comment: I'm using Slackware, and: `# which jobs` gives me expected `which: no jobs in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/kde4/libexec:/usr/lib/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin)`

Comment: And if you print `man jobs` or `jobs -l`?

Comment: @skwllsp no, even if `man -a jobs`. (actually, I've checked that first so be sure I'm not missing something. Google also gave me irrelevant search result)

Comment: Are you using `bash` ? http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_jobs.htm

Comment: @skwllsp yes, I'm using bash (which is actually an alias for `/bin/sh`: `root root 9 *** **  **** /usr/bin/bash -> /bin/bash*` - as it's expected). Strange thing is - that if I try `jobs` or `jobs -l` it result in empty output (not that 'command not found')

Comment: What does `bash --version` output? On my computer: `GNU bash, version 4.1.2`

Comment: @skwllsp `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (i486-slackware-linux-gnu)`

Comment: http://ideone.com/v76H79

Comment: @skwllsp, I am in bash.  `man jobs` results in `No manual entry for jobs`. No output after `jobs -l`. `bash --version`,
`GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: `No output after jobs -l` -  it means no jobs.

Comment: @skwllsp Yes, I can understand that. But I want to know how this _ghost command_ exists in my system (and is not an alias nor regular command and also not listed in any manual page). `find /usr -name "jobs"` or `find /sbin -name "jobs"`  e t.c. gave me nothing

Comment: Can you find it if you do `man bash` and then look for jobs in this man? Or even better `help jobs`?

Comment: `jobs` is a built-in shell command, specified by POSIX and documented in the `bash` man page. However, it will not help with the current situation, because it will only list jobs which are children of the *current* shell.

Comment: @chepner how can I find it? (i.e. is it a binary at all? what is it actually?)

Comment: It is a command interpreted directly by `bash`, like `source`, `alias`, etc. You can't find it somewhere else, because it does not exist external to `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

run your proces with log. I have used gnome-calculator for example:

```
gnome-calculator & echo $! > tmp/11/mylog
```

and add below to `.bashrc` or other autostart for kill it:

```
kill `cat tmp/11/mylog`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pgrep` to find the command:

```
$ pgrep my_task
4384
```

Then you can use that output to make sure it's the command you want:

```
$ ps -fp 4384 | cat
```

I pipe the output to `cat` because the `ps` command will chop off the output at the rowsize of the terminal unless it's piped to another command.

You could combine them too:

```
$ ps -fp $(pgrep my_task) | cat
```

You can also use `pkill` if you're brave:

```
$ pkill my_task
```

This will kill any processes that match the regular expression `my_task` that is owned by the user.